# How to handle Visual Studio 2010 Not Responding?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

First of all, I am not asking the same question here. ( This may be a duplicate post on Stack Overflow.) I have searched other solutions on **MSDN**, **ASP .NET Forum**, **Stack Overflow**, **Code Project** and everywhere on internet. But none of them solved my problem. These are the links that I found:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/01/11/vs-hangs-for-1-minute-on-start-debugging-check-for-dead-symbol-paths.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/272109/Visual-Studio-2010-Hangs-When-Debugging-App

And a lot more...

My **CPU** is 4th Generation Intel Core i7 and **memory** capacity is 8 GB. I think it is  more than recommended hardware requirements.

**Problem:**
My visual studio hangs on these situations.

1. Opening a solution (Hangs for a minute when I open a file from solution explorer)
2. Running the debugging (Freezes consistently when I click on debug button) and
3. Stopping the debugging (Freezes immediately after the UI returns to the Developer layout after debugging)

**I have tried the following steps**:

1. I ensured that I deleted all the breakpoints in the solution.
2. I ensured that I am not using any resources from network drive.
3. I ensured Step over properties is enabled.
4. I ensured Enable .NET Framework source stepping is NOT enabled.
5. I start visual studio with `SafeMode` to suppress extensions
6. I cleared watch window.
7. I cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Before I encounter this problem, I installed "Install Web Components" Visual Studio Add-In a few weeks ago. May be because of extensions and add-ins?

How can I do it to solve my problem?

Comment: How long does it hang?

Comment: @RobertHarvey More than 1 minute.

Comment: Completely uninstall Visual Studio and any beta versions, and reinstall it from scratch.  If that doesn't work, you probably need to pave your machine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Any other solutions? :(

Comment: Not without a whole lot more information which you haven't provided.

Comment: Are you running any third-party libraries that rely on hardware interrupts? Allegro?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: @Casey No Casey. I am not using any third-party libraries. But I downloaded "Install Web Components" Add-In a few weeks ago.

Comment: Was it ever working properly?  When did it stop working?  When you installed the web components?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah I noticed that after I have installed that add-in, Visual Studio became very slow.

Comment: Well, there you go.  The first thing you need to do is uninstall that add-in, or contact the folks that made the add-in and find out why it's making your VS so slow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you suspect that Visual Studio settings get corrupted after installing "Install Web Component" bundle, why don't you try to reset the settings?

You can perform the steps below to reset Visual Studio settings:

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) under Start menu > All Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 > Visual Studio Tools (**Run it with Administrator privilege**: Right-click the program > Run as administrator)
2. Run **devenv /Resetsettings** to restore the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.
3. Run **devenv /ResetSkipPkgs** to clear all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
4. Run **devenv /Safemode** to see if you can apply it correctly. This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or packages are causing problems.
5. Open your solution in **Safemode** and see whether it works.

Comment: devenv/Resetsettings works for me. No need to run in SafeMode. thanks.

Comment: There is few Visual Studio `CMD` tools. I don't know which visual studio tool need to be opened. So I referred this [Visual-Studio-2012-Not-Responding](http://mikeperetz.blogspot.in/2014/04/visual-studio-2012-stop-responding-on.html).

Answer (score 1):

Found this to happen also when the solution is connected to a Team Foundation Server and the service is not available at the moment, so the solution could not connect. In this case do not end the Visual Studio instance and wait until a message box show up giving the option to Go Offline. This is usually associated with the "Visual Studio is waiting for an operation to complete...." notification message.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was simply to reload a saved GOOD (backup) copy of my settings (made a year ago).  Worth trying before resetting everything to blank.  My VS2010 would take 60 seconds to start debugging and approx. 3 minutes to stop debugging.  I saved the corrupted settings and to my surprise they were over 3MB instead of 260Kb.  I loaded the good backup copy and everything is great again  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio doesn't respond only when attempting to open solutions, then open a raw instance of Visual Studio then Reset Settings

Check How to: Reset Your Settings from the Tools Menu

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

This is Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Open developer command prompt.

Start -> All programs -> Visual Studio -> Visual studio tools -> developer command prompt

Make sure that you don't have any pending changes that need to be checked in.

run this command : "tf workspace /delete 'your workspace/ machine name'"

yes for removing the unnecessary pending changes if at all present.